# htmlUnit: how save log line (from terminal) to String?

Tags: java, logging, htmlunit

For example:

`JS executor for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient@1117ac7 2014-06-01 20:46:49,935 WARN  [com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.DefaultCssErrorHandler] CSS warning: 'http://www.infobus.eu/bussystem/find/en/?panel_viev=&point_from_id=&sid=c467d6784b3efd0d15925e786c0c6319' [19:1] Ignoring the following declarations in this rule.`

Because I need to get `sid`, and I don't know why but I not see this `sid` in getted HTML.